# Set Vue Bootstrap Table _rowVariant and row margin

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

i need some ideias to custumize my Vue Boostrap table.

I have some data like:

```
  const tasks = [
    {
      title: 'title 1',
      wbs: '0',
      description: '...'
    },
    {
      title: 'title 2',
      wbs: '1',
      description: '...'
    },
    {
      title: 'title 3',
      wbs: '1.1',
      description: '...'
    },
    {
      title: 'title 4',
      wbs: '1.1.1',
      description: '...'
    },
    {
      title: 'title 5',
      wbs: '1.2',
      description: '...'
    }
  ]
```

my table:

```
     <b-table
        striped
        hover
        isRowHeader
        :responsive="'md'"
        :items="tasks"
        :fields="fields"
        :per-page="perPage"
        :current-page="currentPage"
      />
```

end my tasks are computed from Store:

```
computed: { ...mapGetters({ tasks: "getTasks" }) }
```

I need o custumize the table based on WBS value. Set _rowVariant to 'info' for 0 and 1, to 'warnig' to 1.1 and 1.2, to 'danger' to others. And also add mergin left to title based on WBS size. Plz give some ideia to accomplish this. Ty in advance.

Comment: have you tried anything, facing any error?
or just want the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Add computed new or modify existing to get row variant

```
computed: {
    tasksWithRowVariant() {
  return tasks?.map((task) => {
    let rowVariant
    switch (task.wbs) {
      case '0':
        rowVariant = 'info'
        break
      case '1':
        rowVariant = 'info'
        break
      case '1.1':
        rowVariant = 'warning'
        break
      case '1.2':
        rowVariant = 'warning'
        break
      default:
        rowVariant = 'danger'
    }
    task._rowVariant = rowVariant
    return task
  })
}
 }
```

For margin show what you have tried you would have to use slot to add margin have a look at b-table docs they got good examples there already.

Comment: Ty, this works fine to set my row variant.

Answer (score 1):

I think using the `tbody-tr-class` property is a good solution for your problem. In my opinion, using the features of `b-vue` is better instead of adding complexity to your code with other approaches.

You can see this snippet for a simple example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      fields: [{
          key: "title",
        },
        {
          key: "wbs",
          "tbody-tr-class": (type, key, item) => {
            return 'text-danger'
          }
        },
        {
          key: "description",
        }
      ],
      items: [{
          title: 'title 1',
          wbs: '0',
          description: '...'
        },
        {
          title: 'title 2',
          wbs: '1',
          description: '...'
        },
        {
          title: 'title 3',
          wbs: '1.1',
          description: '...'
        },
        {
          title: 'title 4',
          wbs: '1.1.1',
          description: '...'
        },
        {
          title: 'title 5',
          wbs: '1.2',
          description: '...'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {

    rowClass(item, type) {
      if (item.wbs < 1.1) {
        return "table-info"
      } else if (item.wbs < 1.2) {
        return "table-warning"
      } else {
        return "table-danger"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-table hover :items="items" :tbody-tr-class="rowClass"></b-table>
</div>
```

Comment: Your welcome. Consider accepting if you find it helpful.